# iTunes crashes when syncing music or podcast to my iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone, sync, crash, itunes-10

I have an iPhone 3G that I'm used to be able to sync with my iTunes 10.1 for music and podcasts. Now when I sync an mp3 onto the iPhone, iTunes will crash when trying to transfer the first song with an Invalid Instruction exception.

My computer is Windows 7 x64. I have USB 2.0 ports on it as well.

If I unselect syncing music files (just the calendar and apps) then the phone will sync without issues.

I also have an old 30 GB iPod, and that will sync all music files without issue.

Ideas?

Comment: Does the computer running iTunes has USB 2.0 ports on it?  I have an issue where updating iOS always fails when trying to update on a computer without 2.0 ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated iTunes to 10.1.1.4, and I can sync music again - I don't know what changed, and I can't find the release notes, but seems to be fixed.